# Is there a way to use a for-each loop for an array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, foreach

I'm trying to simplify using a for loop nested in a for loop. I'm using it in a few situations with some code I'm writing, and while there may be other ways of simplification, this was an avenue I was curious about. Probably a simple yes or no answer.

Comment: What language are you using? What does your code look like? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This forum do not allow only yes and no answers. Yes, you can do that in php:

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-php-5/0596005601/ch04s05.html